FXE depiction on VFR sectional - why are there two "beacon stars"?
The airport symbol for FXE (Ft Lauderdale Exec) has two stars for "lighted beacon" on the Miami sectional. Why is there a second star?
There are also two identifier labels for the airport.

The Miami Terminal Area Chart only shows one star / label for FXE.
Additional info: The "double star" / "double label" is also visible direcly from the source on the FAA's VFR Raster Charts (both TIFF and PDF versions), so I don't believe it is a SkyVector thing.

Usually this is because the airport is right on the edge of two different sectionals, and the way SkyVector stitches them together you see the info from each one. In this case FXE is right in the middle of the Miami sectional, and the double info appears as depicted on that one sectional. Could be worth submitting an Aeronautical Inquiry about.

Thanks @randomhead - I just submitted an inquiry. I'll update if/when I hear back!

My foreflight map show double stars in wide range mode, but if I zoom up the map, it only shows one star at the bottom. I guess it’s just a problem of map resolution

@Shin you're just restating OP's question. The sectional shows two stars while the TAC only shows one. (It's not a question of "resolution" as such. Foreflight just automatically switches to the TAC when you zoom in far enough.)

@RalphJ The FAA has VFR raster charts available in TIFF and PDF, and both versions have the "double star" and double label. Also, it's smack dab in the middle of the MIA sectional as randomhead pointed out.

Do you have a paper sectional?

@MichaelHall I do not own a paper MIA chart, but the raster charts which I linked to are official FAA charts.

i don't doubt that they are "official", just wondering if you had a way to verify Randomhead's theory.  Because them being raster charts is likely why.

@MichaelHall The paper charts are just printings of the raster charts. They aren't printed by the FAA or anything so there's no reason to think they will be any different.

@MichaelHall just to be sure of what the others are saying I'll try and get my hands on one! Would be interesting to go back to previous publications and find out when this anomaly started, assuming that's what it is. Too bad I don't think FAA has archive of the raster charts (someone correct me if I'm wrong on that)

Ok, I'm just saying that there's some weirdness at the intersections of charts, I've seen it myself on electronic charts where Sectionals meet a TAC.  This seems like the most valid explanation to me, and worth investigating.

Is the paper chart meant to be a top-half / bottom-half, printed on opposite sides of the paper? If FXE is near that edge, perhaps the info is duplicated so that one prints / is visible when viewing the "top half" side of the chart, and the other for the "bottom half" side? Without seeing the paper chart, I'll spitballing here.

The recto-verso error makes sense as when an aerodrome has actually two beacons (e.g. O22 or UKI), it still appears with a single star on a sectional chart.

OK, so here's what I found. As people mentioned in the comment, the KFXE is depicted on near the bottom half and top half of the sectional charts. One has a star on the top of the airport icon, the other does on the bottom of the airport icon. However, I can tell both of them has two stars apparently...
North half:

South half:


Is it like "top half of chart" on one side of the paper and "bottom side of chart" on the backside? I don't have any VFR charts handy so I'm not 100% clear why Ft Lauderdale is near the edge of the paper.
